# first row merging with table header when i make a table with bootstrap html

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am making a bootstrap table in html.

I see that first row merges with the table header . Hence it is looking very poor.
I tried giving offset but that too does not seem to work.
Iam trying to make a fixed header table , so that when I scroll down , the header remains fixed .

Below is my code:  Can you please let me know what i need to do to fix it :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<style>

    body{
}
.table-fixed{
  width: 100

  tbody{
    height:900px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    width: 100%;

    }
  thead,tbody,tr,td,th{
    display:block;
  }
  tbody{
    td{
      float:left;
    }
  }
  thead {
    tr{
      th{
        float:left;

      }
    }
  }
} 


    th,td {
        width:12.5%;  /*100% number of Cloumn*/
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>


    <div class="container">
  <table class="table table-fixed">
    <thead style="position:fixed" data-offset-top="10">
      <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">First Name</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">Last Name</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr>
        <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr><tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">dd</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">sdffff</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr>



    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your CSS code is invalid, you are using SASS/SCSS syntax rather than CSS. The second last rule should for example be written as `thead tr th { float: left; }`.

Answer (score 0):

take off this :

```
<thead style="position:fixed" data-offset-top="10">
```

Furthermore, dont use `<tr><th>` for table rows. Use it only for header.

Here is a complete working code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
  <table class="table table-fixed">
    <thead style="position:fixed" data-offset-top="10">
      <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1">First Name</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">Last Name</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1">E-mail</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">E-mail</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="col-xs-1">dd</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">sdffff</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">E-mail</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4">E-mail</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```